# Is it okay to use the latest version of opencv?

Tags: opencv, version

I am learning to use opencv. I am trying to install it from opencv official website. Is it okay to install the latest version(4.0.0)? I suppose that latest version should be compatible with the earlier versions so there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it okay to install the latest version(4.0.0)

**Generally: Yes, why not?** If you want to use the newest modules (like [gapi](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/gapi), added in 4.0.0) you will need to use the newest version. It also makes a lot of sense to use the newest because they improved the performance for some operations compared to version 3.x.x.

> I suppose that latest version should be compatible with the earlier versions so there shouldn't be any problem

Not necessarily. Version 4 to 3 might be compatible (I'm still using 3.x.x), but 3 to 2 are in fact not completely compatible. Most noticeable they moved a lot of functionality from the highgui package. From the official change log:

> **Although OpenCV 3 can be viewed as refined OpenCV 2 and is similar to the latter, this new version is not completely backward-compatible with OpenCV 2**

I'd recommend you to read [the official changelog](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) for yourself and decide if you need the new functionality or if you want to stay with an older version. If you are new to OpenCV it probably makes sense to start with the newest version.